# How To Open The Bottom Sheet Behavior Directly To Full Screen with smooth transition?

Tags: android, material-components-android, bottom-sheet

I am looking solution to open the Bottom Sheet Behavior Directly To Full Screen with smooth transition?

Here is the java solution ref link, i am looking kotlin solution.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/bottomsheet/BottomSheetMainDemoFragment.java

```
 private var standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch: BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout>?=null




 /*  bottom sheet search */
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding!!.tripBottomSheetSearch.bottomSheetSearch)
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch!!.isHideable = true
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch!!.peekHeight = 100
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch!!.isDraggable = true
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch!!.skipCollapsed = false
    standardBottomSheetBehaviorSearch!!.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        }
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {    
           
       
        }
    })
```